# How can I filter and find the exact term typed in search field and not using .Contains?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to search and find the exact term in my ASP.NET core application , I am using now .Contains but its show all the terms contains what I type and output not correct I need to find only what I type in the search field ,

This is my DB Repository code :

```
public List<LabResult> Search(string term)
        {
            return db.LabResults.Where(a => a.PatientNo.ToString().Contains(term)).ToList();

        }
```

For example patient no = 250

I need to find only data belongs to this patient no 250

not 2250 or 3250

what I need to use instead of .Contains ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` should do the trick:

```cs
public List<LabResult> Search(string term)
{
    return db.LabResults
        .Where(a => a.PatientNo.ToString() == term)
        .ToList();
}
```

Note that if `PatientNo` is a number you should transform `term` to number and not perform this transform vise versa in the database. Something along this lines (assuming `int` for `PatientNo`):

```cs
public List<LabResult> Search(string term)
{
    if(int.TryParse(term, out var searchNo))
    { 
        return db.LabResults
            .Where(a => a.PatientNo.ToString() == term)
            .ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        // or throw
        return new List<LabResult>();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much its working , yes patient no is number , I will try the second part of solution :)

Comment: can you please check my issue I have another error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437275/how-to-solve-error-system-invalidcastexception-column-contains-null-data