# How to solve error "System.InvalidCastException - column contains NULL data"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-core, datareader

When I run the application and search I got this error

> System.InvalidCastException - column contains NULL data
>
> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal

This is my code DB repository code :

```
public List<LabResult> Search(string term)
{
    return db.LabResults
             .Where(a => a.PatientNo.ToString() == term)
             .ToList(); // error on this line 
}
```

This is the view markup:

```
@model IEnumerable<OracleHIS.Models.LabResult>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PatientNo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LabOrderNo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PatientNameE)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LongForiegnDesc)
            </th>
           <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServNumResult)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model) 
            {
            <tr>
              <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatientNo)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LabOrderNo)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatientNameE)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LongForeignDesc)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServNumResult)
              </td>
              <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
              </td>
           </tr>
        }
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the model class:

```
namespace OracleHIS.Models
{
    public partial class LabResult
    {
        public decimal PatientNo { get; set; } 
        public decimal LabOrderNo { get; set; }
        public string PatientNameE { get; set; } = null!;
        public string LongForiegnDesc { get; set; } = null!;
        public decimal ServNumResult { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I found this solution

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024722/handle-null-values-when-reading-through-oracledatareader
```

but where I will use the `IsDBNull()` in my code?

`OracleDataReader` provides a `IsDBNull()` method.

this is the Model in DBset context its a VIEW not TABLE include columns from multiple tables :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("TRNGKAASH")
                .UseCollation("USING_NLS_COMP");

            modelBuilder.Entity<LabResult>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToView("LAB_RESULTS");

                entity.Property(e => e.AbnormalFlag)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("ABNORMAL_FLAG");

                entity.Property(e => e.ApprovingDateG)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("APPROVING_DATE_G");

                entity.Property(e => e.CancelBy)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("CANCEL_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.CancelDateG)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("CANCEL_DATE_G");

                entity.Property(e => e.CancelDateH)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("CANCEL_DATE_H");

                entity.Property(e => e.CancelReason)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("CANCEL_REASON");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateOfBirth)
                    .HasPrecision(8)
                    .HasColumnName("DATE_OF_BIRTH");

                entity.Property(e => e.EndResult)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("END_RESULT");

                entity.Property(e => e.EventNo)
                    .HasPrecision(4)
                    .HasColumnName("EVENT_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.GramStain)
                    .HasMaxLength(3000)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("GRAM_STAIN");

                entity.Property(e => e.GroupNo)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("GROUP_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.HeparinFlag)
                    .HasPrecision(1)
                    .HasColumnName("HEPARIN_FLAG");

                entity.Property(e => e.HospitalNo)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("HOSPITAL_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.InitDiagnisis)
                    .HasMaxLength(300)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("INIT_DIAGNISIS");

                entity.Property(e => e.LabNo)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("LAB_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.LabOrderNo)
                    .HasPrecision(12)
                    .HasColumnName("LAB_ORDER_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdateDate)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("LAST_UPDATE_DATE");

                entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdateTransaction)
                    .HasMaxLength(1)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("LAST_UPDATE_TRANSACTION");

                entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdateUser)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("LAST_UPDATE_USER");

                entity.Property(e => e.LongForiegnDesc)
                    .HasMaxLength(40)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("LONG_FORIEGN_DESC");

                entity.Property(e => e.MachineId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("MACHINE_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.MedicalCheck)
                    .HasPrecision(1)
                    .HasColumnName("MEDICAL_CHECK");

                entity.Property(e => e.MrMerge)
                    .HasPrecision(12)
                    .HasColumnName("MR_MERGE");

                entity.Property(e => e.Nationality)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("NATIONALITY");

                entity.Property(e => e.PanicFlag)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("PANIC_FLAG");

                entity.Property(e => e.PatientCategory)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("PATIENT_CATEGORY");

                entity.Property(e => e.PatientHospital)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("PATIENT_HOSPITAL");

                entity.Property(e => e.PatientNameA)
                    .HasMaxLength(150)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("PATIENT_NAME_A");

                entity.Property(e => e.PatientNameE)
                    .HasMaxLength(150)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("PATIENT_NAME_E");

                entity.Property(e => e.PatientNo)
                    .HasPrecision(12)
                    .HasColumnName("PATIENT_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.PatientSourceInd)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("PATIENT_SOURCE_IND");

                entity.Property(e => e.PrioFlag)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("PRIO_FLAG");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProvidingResource)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("PROVIDING_RESOURCE");

                entity.Property(e => e.Reason)
                    .HasMaxLength(300)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("REASON");

                entity.Property(e => e.RefSourceNo)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("REF_SOURCE_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.RefType)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("REF_TYPE");

                entity.Property(e => e.ResultNotes)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("RESULT_NOTES");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleCollectedBy)
                    .HasPrecision(5)
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_COLLECTED_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleCollectedDateG)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_COLLECTED_DATE_G");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleCollectedDateH)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_COLLECTED_DATE_H");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleNo)
                    .HasPrecision(12)
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleNote)
                    .HasMaxLength(300)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_NOTE");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleReceivedDateG)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_RECEIVED_DATE_G");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleReceivedDateH)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_RECEIVED_DATE_H");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleRecievedBy)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_RECIEVED_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.SampleType)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("SAMPLE_TYPE");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServCancelBy)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_CANCEL_BY");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServCancelDateG)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_CANCEL_DATE_G");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServCancelDateH)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_CANCEL_DATE_H");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServCancelReason)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_CANCEL_REASON");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServNo)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServNumResult)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_NUM_RESULT");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServRequestDateG)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_REQUEST_DATE_G");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServRequestDateH)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_REQUEST_DATE_H");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServRequestDoctorName)
                    .HasMaxLength(150)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_REQUEST_DOCTOR_NAME");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServRequestDoctorNo)
                    .HasPrecision(5)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_REQUEST_DOCTOR_NO");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServRequestUserId)
                    .HasMaxLength(8)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_REQUEST_USER_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServTextResult)
                    .HasMaxLength(500)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_TEXT_RESULT");

                entity.Property(e => e.ServType)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("SERV_TYPE");

                entity.Property(e => e.Sex)
                    .HasPrecision(1)
                    .HasColumnName("SEX");

                entity.Property(e => e.SpecialCase)
                    .HasPrecision(6)
                    .HasColumnName("SPECIAL_CASE");
            });
```

And this is the VIEW declaration in SQL :

[image]

[image]

I opened view error details and this is the details :

```
 at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at OracleHIS.Models.Repository.LabDbRepository.Search(String term) in D:\HIS\OracleHIS\OracleHIS\Models\Repository\LabDbRepository.cs:line 59
   at OracleHIS.Controllers.LabController.Search(String term) in D:\HIS\OracleHIS\OracleHIS\Controllers\LabController.cs:line 59
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Comment: Don't use `.ToString()` to compare numbers with strings. Parse the string into a number instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how to parse can you post the answer please

Comment: _"how to parse can you post the answer please"_ - this is covered in my answer to your previous question.  Though it is strange that you have `No` columns as decimal, are they decimal in the database?

Comment: As for `null` exception - it means that one of decimal fields is actually nullable in the database, you need to find which one and change corresponding field in the model to nullable `decimal`  (for example `public decimal? ServNumResult { get; set; }`). Also as written in the previous comment - are you sure you need decimals? What actual types are the columns in the database?

Comment: @GuruStron about the column ServNumResult its some times will be null before type the result and the column datatype in oracle database was NUMBER(12,3) because it can be 2340.5

Comment: @ZiadAdnan what about other two? Do they also need to be decimals? Can they be null?

Comment: As for `ServNumResult` - have you tried proposed `decimal?` solution?

Comment: @GuruStron no only this column can be null ServNumResult  all others have value , I commented this field in the view but still show the error

Comment: @GuruStron yes I tried also decimal? in the model but still show the error

Comment: @ZiadAdnan what view? Can you please show how `LabResults` is configured in the dbset? And how the corresponding table/view is declared in sql?

Comment: @GuruStron I added the view in DBSET and SQL thank you for your help sir :)

Comment: @ZiadAdnan all of the properties are listed  as nullable as far as I can see, so change all decimals to be nullable ones, like was suggested for `ServNumResult`. This is valid for other value types like `DateTime`. Also I don't see any number column specifying precision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249610/discussion-between-ziad-adnan-and-guru-stron).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model should match your table/view types including the nullability.

As the table structure shows - all columns can contain `null`'s  so you need to mark all properties that are [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) (i.e. `decimal`s, `int`s, `DateTime`s, etc.) as [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types), as you done with `decimal`'s (note that actual exception has changed the problem datatype after changing `decimal`s to `descimal?`).

If you have [nullable reference types enabled in your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) you may want to mark reference type properties too.

Comment: I checked the columns in the database and DBCONTEXT and made it as it is in the database any column with the type NUMBER(1) or NUMBER(2) or NUMBER(3) I changed it to int and if the column type  NUMBER(4) or greater I changed it to decimal , also changed the type if NULL in the database I changed it to null in the model decimal? , int? , string? , also changed some types read as long? or short? or bool? I changed it as explained before to decimal? int? string? depends on column type in the database , thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the PatientNo to be:

```
public decimal? PatientNo { get; set; }
```

also Don't use .ToString() in where clause

```
    public List<LabResult> Search(string term)
    {
        var decm = Convert.ToDecimal(term)

        return db.LabResults
                 .Where(a => a.PatientNo == decm)
                 .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this solution but still show the same error

Comment: Change the PatientNo to be decimal? and try

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that one of the rows have a null for one of the decimal values. To confirm, execute the following sql statement:

```
Select * from labresults where PatientNo is null or LabOrderNo is null or ServNumResult is null
```

Comment: yes ServNumResult  can be null