# dotnet6 entity framework where clause

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have converted by project from dotnet core 2.1 to dotnet 6. i am in the process of converting it step by step. the thing which i am stuck now is where clause. i am not able to run this simple query in repository

```
  public IQueryable<PostType> getPostType()
    {
       
    

        var d= _context.PostType.Where(e => e.PostStatusId==2).ToList();  // this thing is not working
        return _context.PostType.Where(e => e.PostStatusId == 2);
    }
```

anyone can get why? queries are working before

this is the result

[image]

Posttype

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostType](
[PostTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[PostTypeGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[ParentId] [int] NULL,
[CategoryId] [int] NULL,
[Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Slug] [varchar](500) NULL,
[ThumbnailImg] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[WebSiteId] [int] NULL,
[PostStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
[isMediaType] [bit] NOT NULL,
[isNewsletter] [bit] NOT NULL,
[AllowableExtension] [varchar](100) NULL,
[CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
[ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PostType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PostTypeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PostType_PostTypeGuid]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [PostTypeGuid]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PostType_int_PostStatusId]  DEFAULT ((2)) FOR [PostStatusId]
GO
```

[image]

Comment: "is not working" is not very helpful. How is it not working? Exception? Returns empty result?

Comment: Show us the definition of `class PostType` , and show us your `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that this issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74441572/2501279) and caused by addition of [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and their support in EF Core. See the [Required and optional properties -> Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#conventions) section of the docs:

> C# 8 introduced a new feature called nullable reference types (NRT), which allows reference types to be annotated, indicating whether it is valid for them to contain null or not. This feature is enabled by default in new project templates, but remains disabled in existing projects unless explicitly opted into. Nullable reference types affect EF Core's behavior in the following way:
>
> - If nullable reference types are disabled, all properties with .NET reference types are configured as optional by convention (for example, string).
> - If nullable reference types are enabled, properties will be configured based on the C# nullability of their .NET type: string? will be configured as optional, but string will be configured as required.

Either disable nullable reference types for the project or mark corresponding properties as nullable (in this case some `string` causes the issue, so change `string` to `string?` for corresponding properties).

Comment: It looks like `Slug`, `ThumbnailImg` and `AllowableExtension` all need to be changed from `string` to `string?` if nullable reference types are not disabled.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes

Comment: it doesn't work by changing these three properties. corresponding foreign tables are linked needed to be changed as well?

Comment: @maztt exception changes or is the same?

Comment: it works by disabling

Comment: no the exception is same

Comment: but it worked by disablling

Comment: @maztt it still complains on `get_String`?

Comment: i am sorry.please elloborate get_string? using it in where

Comment: if that is the case case it is working when i use Name in where clause

Comment: it is working using slug in where clause